# Yocto: oe_runmake failed, error in do_compile from bitbake image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm building yocto image and a newbie for this.
I'm having an error when I type `bitbake piflo` command (piflo is my image name) like shown figure below:

[image: oe_runmake failed with do_compile]

It says `ERROR: batctl-2017.1-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed` and also says `pkg-config not found.` from makefile.

I found some solutions from web and tried, but it gave me same error as figure above.
It was building OK but after getting new batctl and batman-adv it fails building.

Does anybody have an idea for this?
Please help me out here.

If needs more information or code, I will EDIT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a broken package. First things first, try cleaning it and rebuilding

```
bitbake -c cleanall batctl  
bitbake -c cleanall batman-adv  
bitbake batman-adv  
bitbake batctl
```

Also, do you actually need those packages? If not just remove them by adding to your local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = " batctl batman-adv "
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I need those packages actually.. :'( I tried what you wrote in answer, and `bitbake batman-adv` went through well but `bitbake batctl` gave me same error like figure in my question... :'(

Comment: The "pkg-config not found" looks suspicious. Do you have it installed on your system? Try to call pkg-config from command line.

Comment: Hm.. you mean like `IMAGE_INSTALL += "pkg-config"`??

Comment: Nope, the host machine. bb recipe on do_compile step usually calls "make" or "oe_runmake", so it just executes makefile. In source code I see    
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config  
  ifeq ($(shell which $(PKG_CONFIG) 2>/dev/null),)  
    $(error $(PKG_CONFIG) not found)  
  endif  
which implies your build system(pc I assume) may not have pkg-config installed.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. When I type `pkg-config --help` or `--version` it shows me version as `0.29.1`

Comment: Isn't that mean pkg-config is installed?? :)

Comment: Yocto does not use host pkg-config so that's not the issue. "inherit pkgconfig" in the broken  recipe might help it find the yocto pkg-config .

Comment: Wow, that's strange. Makefile checks if "which pkg-config" command returns path to binary, if not it's assumed you don't have it on your system and failure occurs. As a dirty hack you can comment out lines 62-67 and check if it helps.

Comment: @jku @metamorphling Thanks for all the replies I figured out what I was wrong, From bb file, originally I wrote like `DEPENDS = "libnl"` only, but after I change that to `DEPENDS = "libnl pkgconfig-native"` it went thorough OK! :D Thanks alot for helping me out guys!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like you just found out, you need to add `pkg-config` to your recipe's `DEPENDS`.

In earlier OpenEmbedded (Yocto) it often worked out anyway, as some other recipe had `pkg-config` in its `DEPENDS`. However, from the `Pyro` release, each recipe gets it's own sysroot; thus, you have to explicitly add everything that the recipe needs to it's `DEPENDS`. This is done to improve determinism in the builds.